# How do I get and use value from a tensor within a TF 2.0 Dataset map step?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using TensorFlow Alpha 2.0.

I have TFRecords files I'm reading from, each one holding a short video clip with each frame encoded as jpeg byte string to save space:

```
{
  'numframes': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
  'frames': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.string)
}
```

I have a map step in my tf.data.Dataset pipeline that successfully parses each example:

```
def parse_tfrecord(p):
    return tf.io.parse_single_example(p, example_schema)
```

My next step is to read out the number of frames from `numframes` and run the tf.io.decode_jpeg function on each frame in `frames.values[i]` with `i` being from `range(numframes)`:

```
def parse_jpegs(p):
    numframes = p['numframes']
    return tf.map_fn(tf.io.decode_jpeg, [p['frames'].values[i] for i in range(numframes)])
```

My dataset pipeline for completeness:

```
def dataset():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("*.tfrecord")
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(dataset)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat()
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_tfrecord)
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_jpegs)
    return dataset
```

If I exclude the `dataset.map(parse_jpegs)` line it all works alright, showing me something like `{'frames': <tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor at 0x7f394c285518>, 'numframes': <tf.Tensor: id=2937, shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=25>}`

(Note that the numframes tensor includes a numpy value of 25. I can get that outside my dataset pipeline with the tensor.numpy() method)

Within that map function though, I can't call .numpy() to get the value out of the tensor, and when printing the tensor itself it hasn't been evaluated or something because there is no value shown yet.

What is the best way to parse all these frames within the dataset pipeline?

EDIT: Error message I'm getting is `TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` in parse_jpegs when trying to get numframes. This makes sense to me why a tensor can't be interpreted as an int, but how can I get the value from that tensor to use to set the range?

The problem I'm running into comes down to the fact that each "frames" object has a different number of frames. If I can apply `tf.io.decode_jpeg` to each frame in that list without needing to record number of frames separately I would be fine with that, but I have "numframes" here so I know how many frames need to be decoded in my "frames" list.

**EDIT**: I'll heave the question up for anyone else who might find it helpful, but I ended up just returning the raw bytestrings and doing the decode_jpeg in a separate generator function outside the dataset API. It was much easier that way, even if it might be slower.

Comment: It's not completely clear why you're using numframes as a tensor? Please add error message

Comment: @Sharky You're right, I want to be using it as an int. How can I get the value out of the tensor in my `parse_jpegs` function?

Comment: try `tf.decode_raw(p['numframes'], tf.int64)`

Comment: I'm getting an error on `tf.decode_raw(...)` of `Input 'bytes' of 'DecodeRaw' Op has type int64 that does not match expected type of string.`. Indeed if I do a quick `    print(p['numframes'].dtype)
` it shows me that p['numframes'] dtype is int64 already. If I try to index into my `p['frames']` array with `p['numframes']` it complains that it's still a tensor, but `p['numframes'].numpy()` doesn't work because numpy() isn't a method on it.

Comment: Ok, try for loop over `tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator('file.tfrecords')`  On every item, `
`tf.train.Example().features.feature['numframes'].int64_list.value[0]` 
what is the output?

Comment: Should it work exactly as you have it written? I was able to run (hopefully the same thing) `b = tf.io.parse_single_example(a, example_schema)['numframes'].numpy()` which worked and gave me `22` which is perfect, this example is 22 frames. Within a function applied to the dataset with `map` though the numpy() method doesn't exist. Neither does `int64_list` or `value`. If I take a step back am I even thinking about this the right way? "frames" is a SparseTensor, with a varible sequence length of frames encoded as individual jpegs. Is there a better way to store a video in a tfrecords file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190117/discussion-between-sharky-and-maccam912).

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case, I ended up finding out that map_fn was trying to turn my input tensor into an output tensor of the same type. In this case, `tf.io.decode_jpeg` takes in a string (of bytes) and outputs a uint8 array, which was causing problems. Another argument to `tf.map_fn(... output_type=tf.uint8)` seems to have fixed it for me! Maybe not exactly as written since I continued tinkering with it since asking the question, but I got it working now.